# Can't embed CV2 outputted recording to HTML's <video> tag?

Tags: python, html, opencv, flask

I am working on making a CC Camera project in *python*. My main idea was to get snippets of recordings like 30 seconds each video, which would then be displayed onto my Html, hosting a *flask* server. I used OpenCV to get the recordings, and basic *HTML* to display my video. But, I ran into an *error*, where my video outputted by OpenCV doesn't get displayed on my `index.html`.  I even tried to debug this problem, so I downloaded a video recording online, which did end up working. So, I knew that something was wrong with the recording outputted by OpenCV, but I can't quite figure out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

VideoRecorder.py: This code should run for 30 seconds, and output a Video.avi

```
import time, cv2

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
out = cv2.VideoWriter('Video.avi', fourcc, 30.0,(int(cap.get(3)),int(cap.get(4))))

def video_capture():
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        end_time = time.time() - start_time
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if end_time <= 30:
            out.write(frame)
        else:
            break

    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

video_capture()
```

Index.html (Used Chrome)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}"> -->
        <title>Live Video</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <Center>
        <h1> Live Video </h1>
        <video width=640 height=480 controls>
            <source src="Video.avi" type="video/avi">
            Your Browser Doesn't Support The Video Tag
        </video>
        </Center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works for me, creating a somewhat large video.  Did you try playing the video on your desktop?  You're sure you've copied it to the right location on the server?

Comment: You know, that refresh is going to abort things every minute, whether it's in the middle of downloading the file or playing the file.

Comment: The video does play on my desktop, but whenever I try linking it to the html page it never works. Like it just shows a black screen on chrome.

Comment: Chrome doesn't support MJPG.  It actually supports very few formats.  Can you have cv2 create an MP4?

Comment: Yup, I tried using that too, but that didn't work out either. I used several different formats including MP4 but no progress.